# Gazebo ROS Collision Detection

Tags: ros, gazebo, collision, plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am trying to get a topic with the collision by using the gazebo-ros-bumper plugin, but all of the resources I have found online have not worked for me.

Here is my xacro code for the robot arm.

```
<!-- ***************Robot Arms*************** -->
<xacro:include filename="$(find robsim_description)/urdf/kuka.xacro" />

<!-- ***************Robot Hands*************** -->
<xacro:include filename="$(find robsim_description)/urdf/sdhhand.xacro" />

<!-- ***************Joint*************** -->
<xacro:rev_joint_block parent="arm_extension" child="sdh_gehaeuse" xyz="0 0 0.0411" rpy="0 0 0" lower="0" upper="0"/>

<!-- ***************Gazebo Plugin************************ -->
<gazebo>
    <plugin name="gazebo_ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
        <robotNamespace>/robarm</robotNamespace>
    </plugin>
</gazebo>
```

Here is the code for my kuka arm:

```
<xacro:macro name="link_block" params="link xyz rpy filename material">
    <link name="${link}">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="${xyz}" rpy="${rpy}"/>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://robsim_description/models/${filename}"/>
            </geometry>
        </visual>
        
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="${xyz}" rpy="${rpy}"/>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://robsim_description/models/${filename}"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        
        <inertial>
            <mass value="1"/>
            <inertia ixx="0.1" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.1" iyz="0" izz="0.1"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>
    
    <gazebo reference="${link}">
        <turnGravityOff>true</turnGravityOff>
        <material>Gazebo/${material}</material>
    </gazebo>
</xacro:macro>

<xacro:macro name="rev_joint_block" params="parent child xyz rpy lower upper">
    <joint name="${parent}_${child}_joint" type="revolute">
        <parent link="${parent}"/>
        <child link="${child}"/>
        <origin xyz="${xyz}" rpy="${rpy}"/>
        <axis xyz="0 0 1" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <limit lower="${lower}" upper="${upper}" effort="300.0" velocity="1000.0"/>
        <joint_properties damping="0.0" friction="0.0"/>
    </joint>
</xacro:macro>

<xacro:macro name="transmission_block" params="parent child">
  <transmission name="${parent}_${child}_trans">
        <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
        <joint name="${parent}_${child}_joint">
            <hardwareInterface>PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        </joint>
        <actuator name="${parent}_${child}_motor">
            <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
        </actuator>
    </transmission>
</xacro:macro>

<!-- ***************Kuka Base Plate*************** -->
<xacro:link_block link="base_link" xyz="0 0 0.016" rpy="0 0 0" filename="kuka_base_plate.dae" material="Grey"/>

<!-- ***************Kuka A1 Joint***************** -->
<xacro:link_block link="a1" xyz="0 0 0.016" rpy="0 0 0" filename="a1.dae" material="Orange"/>
<joint name="base_a1" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="a1"/>
</joint>

<!-- ***************Kuka A2 Joint**************** -->
<xacro:link_block link="a2" xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" filename="a2.dae" material="Orange"/>
<xacro:rev_joint_block parent="a1" child="a2" xyz="0 0 0.3265" rpy="0 0 0" lower="-2.96706" upper="2.96706"/>
<xacro:transmission_block parent="a1" child="a2"/>

<!-- ***************Kuka E1 Joint**************** -->
<xacro:link_block link="e1" xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" filename="e1.dae" material="Orange"/>
<xacro:rev_joint_block parent="a2" child="e1" xyz="0 0 0" rpy="1.5707 3.14159 0" lower="0" upper="3.14159"/>
<xacro:transmission_block parent="a2" child="e1"/>

<!-- ***************Kuka A3 Joint**************** -->
<xacro:link_block link="a3" xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" filename="a3.dae" material="Orange"/>
<xacro:rev_joint_block parent="e1" child="a3" xyz="-0.4 0 0" rpy="-1.5707 0 1.5707" lower="-2.0944" upper="2.0944"/>
<xacro:transmission_block parent="e1" child="a3"/>

<!-- ***************Kuka A4 Joint**************** -->
<xacro:link_block link="a4" xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" filename="a4.dae" material="Orange"/>
<xacro:rev_joint_block parent="a3" child="a4" xyz="0 0 0" rpy="-1.5707 0 0" lower="-2.96706" upper="2.96706"/>
<xacro:transmission_block parent="a3" child="a4"/>

<!-- ***************Kuka A5 Joint**************** -->
<xacro:link_block link="a5" xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" filename="a5.dae" material="Orange"/>
<xacro:rev_joint_block parent="a4" child="a5" xyz="0 -0.39 0" rpy="1.5707 0 0" lower="-2.0944" upper="2.0944"/>
<xacro:transmission_block parent="a4" child="a5"/>

<!-- ***************Kuka A6 Joint**************** -->
<xacro:link_block link="a6" xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" filename="a6.dae" material="Grey"/>
<xacro:rev_joint_block parent="a5" child="a6" xyz="0 0 0" rpy="1.5707 0 0" lower="-2.96706" upper="2.96706"/>
<xacro:transmission_block parent="a5" child="a6"/>

<!-- ***************Kuka Tool Plate Joint*************** -->
<xacro:link_block link="tool_plate" xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" filename="tool_plate.dae" material="Grey"/>
<xacro:rev_joint_block parent="a6" child="tool_plate" xyz="0 0.078 0" rpy="-1.5707 0 0" lower="-2.96706" upper="2.96706"/>
<xacro:transmission_block parent="a6" child="tool_plate"/>

<!-- ***************Kuka Arm Extention Joint*************** -->
<xacro:link_block link="arm_extension" xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" filename="arm_extension.dae" material="Grey"/>
<joint name="arm_extension" type="fixed">
    <parent link="tool_plate"/>
    <child link="arm_extension"/>
</joint>
```

Here is the code for the SDH Hand:

```
<xacro:macro name="link_block" params="link xyz rpy filename material">
    <link name="${link}">
        <visual name="${link}_visual">
            <origin xyz="${xyz}" rpy="${rpy}"/>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://robsim_description/models/${filename}"/>
            </geometry>
        </visual>
        
        <collision name="${link}_collision">
            <origin xyz="${xyz}" rpy="${rpy}"/>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://robsim_description/models/${filename}"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        
        <inertial>
            <mass value="1"/>
            <inertia ixx="0.1" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.1" iyz="0" izz="0.1"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>
    
    <gazebo reference="${link}">
        <turnGravityOff>true</turnGravityOff>
        <material>Gazebo/${material}</material>

    </gazebo>
</xacro:macro>

<xacro:macro name="rev_joint_block" params="parent child xyz rpy lower upper">
    <joint name="${parent}_${child}_joint" type="revolute">
        <parent link="${parent}"/>
        <child link="${child}"/>
        <origin xyz="${xyz}" rpy="${rpy}"/>
        <axis xyz="0 0 1" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <limit lower="${lower}" upper="${upper}" effort="300.0" velocity="1000.0"/>
        <joint_properties damping="0.0" friction="0.0"/>
    </joint>
</xacro:macro>

<xacro:macro name="transmission_block" params="parent child">
  <transmission name="${parent}_${child}_trans">
        <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
        <joint name="${parent}_${child}_joint">
            <hardwareInterface>PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        </joint>
        <actuator name="${parent}_${child}_motor">
            <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
        </actuator>
    </transmission>
</xacro:macro>

<!-- ***************SDH Hand Gehaeuse*************** -->
<xacro:link_block link="sdh_gehaeuse" xyz="0 0 0.0743" rpy="0 0 0" filename="sdh_gehaeuse.dae" material="Grey"/>

<!-- ***************Finger 1************************ -->
<xacro:link_block link="gelenk_1" xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" filename="sdh_gelenk_finger1_simplified.dae" material="Grey"/>
<xacro:rev_joint_block parent="sdh_gehaeuse" child="gelenk_1" xyz="0.019052 -0.033 0.0908" rpy="0 0 1.5707" lower="-1.5707" upper="1.5707"/>
<xacro:transmission_block parent="sdh_gehaeuse" child="gelenk_1"/>

<xacro:link_block link="mittelteil_1" xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" filename="sdh_mittelteil_finger1_mass.dae" material="Grey"/>
<xacro:rev_joint_block parent="gelenk_1" child="mittelteil_1" xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 -1.5707 0" lower="-1.5707" upper="1.5707"/>
<xacro:transmission_block parent="gelenk_1" child="mittelteil_1"/>

<xacro:link_block link="kuppe_1" xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" filename="sdh_kuppe_finger1.dae" material="Grey"/>
<xacro:rev_joint_block parent="mittelteil_1" child="kuppe_1" xyz="0.0865 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" lower="-1.5707" upper="1.5707"/>
<xacro:transmission_block parent="mittelteil_1" child="kuppe_1"/>

<!-- ***************Finger 2************************ -->
<xacro:link_block link="gelenk_2" xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" filename="sdh_gelenk_finger1_simplified.dae" material="Grey"/>
<xacro:rev_joint_block parent="sdh_gehaeuse" child="gelenk_2" xyz="-0.038105 0 0.0908" rpy="0 0 -1.5707" lower="-1.5707" upper="1.5707"/>
<xacro:transmission_block parent="sdh_gehaeuse" child="gelenk_2"/>

<xacro:link_block link="mittelteil_2" xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" filename="sdh_mittelteil_finger1_mass.dae" material="Grey"/>
<xacro:rev_joint_block parent="gelenk_2" child="mittelteil_2" xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 -1.5707 0" lower="-1.5707" upper="1.5707"/>
<xacro:transmission_block parent="gelenk_2" child="mittelteil_2"/>

<xacro:link_block link="kuppe_2" xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" filename="sdh_kuppe_finger1.dae" material="Grey"/>
<xacro:rev_joint_block parent="mittelteil_2" child="kuppe_2" xyz="0.0865 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" lower="-1.5707" upper="1.5707"/>
<xacro:transmission_block parent="mittelteil_2" child="kuppe_2"/>

<!-- ***************Finger 3************************ -->
<xacro:link_block link="gelenk_3" xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" filename="sdh_gelenk_finger1_simplified.dae" material="Grey"/>
<xacro:rev_joint_block parent="sdh_gehaeuse" child="gelenk_3" xyz="0.019052 0.033 0.0908" rpy="0 0 1.5707" lower="-1.5707" upper="1.5707"/>
<xacro:transmission_block parent="sdh_gehaeuse" child="gelenk_3"/>

<xacro:link_block link="mittelteil_3" xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" filename="sdh_mittelteil_finger1_mass.dae" material="Grey"/>
<xacro:rev_joint_block parent="gelenk_3" child="mittelteil_3" xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 -1.5707 0" lower="-1.5707" upper="1.5707"/>
<xacro:transmission_block parent="gelenk_3" child="mittelteil_3"/>

<xacro:link_block link="kuppe_3" xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" filename="sdh_kuppe_finger1.dae" material="Grey"/>
<xacro:rev_joint_block parent="mittelteil_3" child="kuppe_3" xyz="0.0865 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" lower="-1.5707" upper="1.5707"/>
<xacro:transmission_block parent="mittelteil_3" child="kuppe_3"/>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240076/gazebo-ros-collision-detection/) by [justinkgoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27238/justinkgoh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2016-07-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2016-07-21**:
Where is your bumper plugin defined?
And I'm also trying bumper simulation now and found the [wiki](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins#Bumper) might not be accurate. I'll edit it once I confirm the right way.

**Comment by [justinkgoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27238/justinkgoh/) on 2016-07-22**:
I have tried it in several places. Including the one you suggested in the gazebo wiki site. The other ones I have tried are from [here](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/issues/260) and [here](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5355/adding-ros-integrated-contact-sensors/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Which link do you want to create a bumper on? You need to create a contact sensor first. I had a hard time getting this to run as well. I've attached some example code which you can edit as necessary. This code is in my `atlas.gazebo` file

```
<gazebo reference="your_link">
<!-- contact sensor -->
<sensor type="contact" name="your_link_contact_sensor">
  <update_rate>1000.0</update_rate>
  <always_on>1</always_on>
  <contact>
    <collision>bumper_collision</collision>
    <topic>/bumper_contact</topic>
  </contact>
<plugin name="gazebo_ros_bumper_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_bumper.so">
        <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
        <updateRate>1000.0</updateRate>
        <bumperTopicName>/robot_bumper</bumperTopicName>
        <frameName>world</frameName>
</plugin>
</sensor>
```

---

Originally posted by [Mav16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27867/mav16/) with karma: 38 on 2016-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0